# arcpy.CopyFeatures between file GDBs?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000210

I'm trying to figure out why I can't copy a featureclass from one file GDB to another. I can copy the featureclass to within the source GDB. There's no name conflict in the target GDB. I don't think I've set any GDB constraints that would stop me. I'm running 10.0 ArcGIS. Any thoughts?

Here's what I've done to explore a bit and the error that I get.

```
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.env.workspace
u'C:\\Workspace\\wk_NHDPlus/NHDPlus03_Final.gdb/PRMS'
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.env.overwriteOutput
True
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.Exists('nsegment_flowlinesFL')
True
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.GetCount_management('nsegment_flowlinesFL')
<Result '5530'>
[Dbg]>>> desc = arcpy.Describe('nsegment_flowlinesFL')
[Dbg]>>> desc.dataElement.catalogPath
u'C:\\Workspace\\wk_NHDPlus\\NHDPlus03_wk.gdb\\Output\\nsegment_flowlines'
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('nsegment_flowlinesFL', 'C:\\Workspace\\wk_NHDPlus\\NHDPlus03_wk.gdb\\Output\\junk')
<Result 'C:\\Workspace\\wk_NHDPlus\\NHDPlus03_wk.gdb\\Output\\junk'>
[Dbg]>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('nsegment_flowlinesFL', 'C:\\Workspace\\wk_NHDPlus\\NHDPlus03_Final.gdb\\PRMS\\junk')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1943, in CopyFeatures
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Workspace\wk_NHDPlus\NHDPlus03_Final.gdb\PRMS\junk
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Comment: Does the feature rely on any coded values or have any topology dependencies?

Comment: Does the PRMS FeatureDataset already exist?  Are there any locks on the Final.gdb?

Comment: If the source or target is in a feature dataset with a topology that can create problems copying.

Comment: @RyanDalton: yes the PRMS FeatureDataset does already exist.

Comment: @Geoist and johns (sorry can only reference one person in a comment apparently): There is topology in the class, but none of the rules pertain to the featureclass in particular. I could definitely be overlooking something. I'm a bit of superficial topology user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give this point to @RyanDalton for his comment about checking for file locks, which turned out to be my issues. I'll select this answer as correct to make it easier for subsequent readers. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

You should test for "junk" in NHDPlus03_Final.gdb.

`print arcpy.Exists(C:\\\Workspace\\\wk_NHDPlus\\\NHDPlus03_Final.gdb\\\junk)`

This will return True if "junk" exists anywhere in the geodatabase, including in a FeatureDataSet.
You cannot duplicate a FeatureClass name in a geodatabase, even if you have FeatureDataSets
to help organize your data.

Comment: I'll check that. I do have most of my content nested under a FeatureDataset. I could be missing the presence of "junk" elsewhere. I didn't do this originally because `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True` and figured whatever there would get clobbered--but this won't work if it's outside of the FeatureDataset I'm trying to use.